# Android Studio Gradle Closures: No Such Property

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, closures

I am still new to the gradle/groovy world. I am trying to make use of closures in my code. At the moment I am using Android Studio Version 1.2

Every time I try to use closures and call variables inside it, it seems to print "No Such Property" Error.

Simple Example:

```
def clos = { a, b -> 
    println a
    println b
}
```

This will throw out no such property a error.

Can someone please help out with this! Thank you in advance!